# Not able to find .config file for conversion to .tflite

Tags: python, tensorflow, protocol-buffers, config

I am trying to use https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/export_tflite_graph_tf2.py method to convert a saved model to .tflite.

The example usage for that is:

```
python3 models/research/object_detection/export_tflite_graph_tf2.py \
--trained_checkpoint_dir {'ssd_mobilenet_v2_fpnlite_640x640_coco17_tpu-8/checkpoint'} \
--output_directory {'ssd_mobilenet_v2_fpnlite_640x640_coco17_tpu-8/tflite'} \
--pipeline_config_path {'ssd_mobilenet_v2_fpnlite_640x640_coco17_tpu-8/pipeline.config'}
```

That project needs pipeline.config file which I am missing in mine or don't see it as is. Is it possible to generate pipeline.config? I am open to other solutions too.